# Passing a series into a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a `dict`, `ht`, where the key is an `int`, and the value is a conversion factor.

I also have a dataframe `df`, with a column `id` that stores `int` variables, and another column, `vals`, that I need to multiply to relevant conversion factors according to `id`, which will be the key input into `ht`.

I would like to do something like

```
conversions = ht[df["id"]]
df["vals"] *= conversions
```

But this gives the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You would want the first line to be `ht[df["id"]]`, right?  You can add `conversions`as another column, then multiply the two columns.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh right, just made the change. Do you mean to do something like df["conversions"] = ht[df["id"]]? Wouldn't that result in the same error since the issue is associated with the `ht[df["id"]]` part?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) to get the dictionary value for each value in the series.

```
conversions = df["id"].map(ht)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete solution with some higher order function.

```py
"""Mapping values"""

import pandas as pd

# ht dictionary
ht = {1: 2.0,
      2: 3.0,
      3: 4.0}

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id'  : [1, 2, 3],
     'vals': [10, 20, 30]}
    )
# use map to apply conversion factors from ht to df
df["vals"] = df["vals"] * df["id"].map(ht)

print(df)
```

Indexed Printout

```bash
   id   vals 
0   1   20.0 
1   2   60.0 
2   3  120.0
```

Comment: There is no recursion here.  Why would you say there was?